# Showing messages while loading, like loading or no more data in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing infinite scrolling technique in one of my views, and it is working. the script I used is given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      GetArticlesFromNextSection(true);
    }
  });
  var i = 2;
  function GetArticlesFromNextSection(scrollPage) {
    var pagenumber = i++;
    $("#divLoading").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.post('/Channel/MessagePagination', {
        "pagenumber": pagenumber,
      },
      function (data) {
        if (data == "") {
          $("#divLoading").html("No More Posts");
        }
        $("#messagelist").append(data);
        $("#divLoading").hide();
      });         
    }, 1000);
    i = i;
  }
</script>
```

Now I need to show a message like no more data or something like that when data is loaded completely.
I have given a if condition to check that

```
if (data == "") { $("#divLoading").html("No More Posts");}
```

but it is not working. Can anyone tell me what will be the problem?
the view and controller sample code is given below

View:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div id="messagelist">
    @{Html.RenderPartial( "mypartial",list);}
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001; opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
  <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">Loading, please wait...<img src="~/images/loading.png"></p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MessagePagination(int pagenumber)
{
  var balObject = new BusinessLogic();
  int pageSize = 3;
  var MessageList = balObject.FetchMessages();
  MessageList = MessageList.Skip((pagenumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
  return PartialView("mypartial", MessageList);
}
```

Comment: If the count of `MessageList` is zero, return `null` and in the success function, `if(!data){no more posts}`

Comment: thank you. I used the same logic and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the controller to return null if the msglist count is zero.
And I used an alert box to display the message no more posts to display.
now its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check like this:

```
if ($.trim(data)) {
$("#messagelist").append(data);
$("#divLoading").hide();
}
else
 $("#divLoading").html("No More Posts");
```

or you can use `length` property after trimming if it is greater than 0 data came else not came (it is in the case if you are return empty string from server when no more data):

```
if ($.trim(data).length) {
    $("#messagelist").append(data);
    $("#divLoading").hide();
    }
    else
     $("#divLoading").html("No More Posts");
```

Comment: It is checking the condition and it is working. but the message 'no more post is not coming' in the 'divloading.

Comment: make sure that id is ame and it is going in else part

Comment: No, I checked everything. its something else. but, I used an alert box instead .html and now its enough.
like `else { alert("No more posts to fetch"); $("#divLoding").hide();}`